# Compilation error: "Could not complete external evaluation at..."

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, data-types

I'm pretty new to trying to use `Compile[]`, and I just can't see why I'm getting this error.

I have two functions to define beforehand; one of them is a bit odd:

```
Sparsifier[n_Integer] := 
Table[With[{l = (L - 1)/2 + 1}, 
Normal@SparseArray[{{1, l} -> 1., {l, L} -> 1., {l, 1} -> 
   1., {L, l} -> 1.}]], {L, 3, 2 n, 2}]`
```

This generates an array of sparse arrays that have 1s in the middle of each outermost side, as follows:

```
MatrixForm /@ Sparsifier[5]`
```

[image: array of sparse arrays]

```
Meaner2[ar_List] := Mean[Compile[{{lst, _Real, 1}}, Select[lst, Positive], 
CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
Parallelization -> True][Flatten@ar]]`
```

This takes a list of arbitrary dimensions as input, picks out all of the non-zero entries, and takes their mean.

I feel like I have an okay understanding of what's happening up to here. I then use these functions as follows:

```
Convolver4[ar_List] := With[{Stab = Sparsifier[Length[ar]]},
ParallelMap[
Meaner2[
 ar ListConvolve[#, ar,
   .5 (Length[#] + 1) {1, -1},
   0, Times, List]
       ] &,
      Stab]]
```

(sorry if this looks weird; please let me know if there's a preferred way to make this kind of thing readable!)

This function is... hard to describe verbally, but I have a good handle on what it does. (it's something like a correlation function, the r^th element of the list is C(r) for that "radius".) I can try and explain this if it's important to the problem.

In any case, I try to compile this function in the hopes of speeding all of this up—currently, it takes *way* too long to use this `Convolver4` function for my current purposes—but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get this working. I've tried incorporating the the sparse arrays into the compilation variables; I've tried moving Withs in and out of the Compile; I've tried padding the sparse arrays with 0s to make them all the same size; I've really tried everything I can think of. I've also done a lot of searching, but the issues with `Compile` often seem pretty particular to my uneducated eye.

Some of these seem to fail because at least one of these functions I'm using doesn't compile and has to go to the main evaluator, but given that this takes impossibly long to run, I either have to hope compilation speeds it up or figure out a way to optimize it. Help with either would be massively appreciated!

Comment: A quick observation - you are running the C compiler each time `Meaner2` is called.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't even considered that that might be slower—the function is already much faster than using `Cases`, as I'd been doing before, so I didn't even think to try *not* compiling to C (amateur mistake). I think that the longest part of this is still the convolution, though—I've no idea how to speed that up. 

I thought about generating something like a `CrossMatrix` and doing element by element multiplication, but you can't pick the center of the cross. I could `ArrayPad`, but with that and extracting all of the products, I don't think it'd be any faster...

Comment: The Compile is fine, but you only need to compile once. `f = Compile[...]` then use `f` in Meaner2. Also what size is the array?

Comment: Ha! I'd had the function set up like that, but I tried to make it cleaner and I see what I've done now. I should have known, now that I have a better feel for how `SetDelayed` works. Thanks for the pointer!

The arrays I need to use this for are ~750x750. I've realized that storing an array of all of the arrays of neighbor-products at a distance r and then taking the mean is probably slowing everything down massively due to writing and retrieving all of this from memory...

Comment: I think my next attempt will be to take the mean of the non- zero neighbor-products for each entry, then take the mean of all of the means. The only catch with that is that I'll have to add a "weight" factor to each one, since I don't want the corner and side cases to be counted the same as the inner cases, given that they only have 2-3 neighbors rather than 4.